# "Failed to execute child process “python” (No such file or directory)"

Tags: 18.04, atom

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

When I try to run a program through the atom text editor I get this error in the terminal:

> Failed to execute child process “python” (No such file or directory)

[image: This is the screenshot of my screen]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply go ahead and create a symlink(softlink) using the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```